# Evaluating expression of Facelets components in Richfaces sort

Tags: sorting, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I have some problem evaluating expression in a Facelets component defined in a .taglib.xml

```
SortField2.getExpression()
```

gives me the value "#{sortBy}" instead of evaluating the value.

My component (a simple column) is defined as:

```
  <ui:composition>
      <rich:column sortBy="#{sortBy}" width="#{width}" styleClass="#{styleClass}">
          <f:facet name="header">#{header}</f:facet>
          <ui:insert />
      </rich:column>
  </ui:composition>
```

I see that in TagValueExpression there is a "original" field which contains my value, but unfortunately it is private.

Any idea on how to extract it?

Also posted on [Richfaces Forum](http://community.jboss.org/thread/156790?tstart=0)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get "sortExpression" to work, instead of using "sortBy".

Also, instead of `#{sortBy}`, would `${sortBy}` do any good? (A long shot)